# documentation on how to set up vim for python?

Tags: linux, vim

Okay so apparently VIM is a really good text editor and I want to start using it for Python. I installed lubuntu (VM) and I did the command sudo apt-get install vim-gtk, but im wondering now how to set up vim for python? Is this documented anywhere? I'm new to linux. Can someone help me out with this? What's the next step after sudo apt-get install vim-gtk?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. But adding line to `~/.vimrc` means adds lines in the file `~/.vimrc`. if its not there create it.

Comment: I just mentioned the ~/.vimrc part because when I was trying to look for tutorials, I saw that a few times.. okay so what would my next step be after doing sudo apt-get install vim-gtk, do I now have vim with python syntax? how do I use it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, Vim will never be an IDE; it's just a text editor (geared towards programmers) that has great capabilities, and can be greatly extended, but it will never be a consistent, fully-integrated entity.

That said, people have managed to set up Vim for productive development in a variety of languages, but, unless "real" IDEs, some effort and learning will be required on your side. Best start by perusing blog articles like these:

- [Turning Vim into a modern Python IDE](http://sontek.net/blog/detail/turning-vim-into-a-modern-python-ide)
- [VIM as Python IDE](http://blog.dispatched.ch/2009/05/24/vim-as-python-ide/)

Comment: but reading the first line of that page in the intro section, it says 'mkdir ~/.vim/'.. how do I do that? I opened up my terminal and typed that and it did nothing, in which directory do I do "mkdir ~/.vim/" in?

Comment: @user216485 Most likely it worked. In unix no output normally means it worked. Just do a `cd ~/.vim` to go into the directory. And go read a good book on how to use the command line.

Comment: Hm okay so when I need to turn off file type detection, I cd ~/.vim/, git init and then how do I go into the actual file? It says "add the following to your ~/.vimrc".. after I did  cd ~/.vim/ and typed filetype off, it said filetype: command not found

Comment: @user216485 do it in vim... not bash... and to open the file in vim. Do a `vim ~/.vimrc`

Comment: @FDinoff when i do vim ~/.vimrc, it opens something which says stuff like .git/ .autoload/ .bundle/ .netrwhist .swp and it doesn't allow me to type anything in there.

Comment: @user216485 it sounds like you made `~/.vimrc` a directory instead of a file

Comment: @FDinoff ya I follwed the instructions which was provided in the first link of the answer.. I did mkdir ~/.vim/, mkdir ~/.vim/{autoload,bundle}, cd ~/.vim/ and then git init... mkdir makes a directory right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34775/discussion-between-user216485-and-fdinoff)

Comment: You are doing too much at the same time. Learn the basics of the unix command line first (there are plenty of tutorials, use google) and then, learn vim and then learn python. Or simply install pycharm or some other python IDE and forget all about those command line shennanigans.